# Anonymous survey posted on Survey Monkey

Tags: discussion, status-completed

An anonymous survey has been posted on Survey Monkey.  It asks questions about your perception of the Pets.SE site

https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/YGCQKZF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a summary of the answers that were collected last week:

**What brings you to visit Pets.SE? What are you looking for in the site?**

- Looking for information about pets people own.
- Also looking to share information about pets people own (answering questions).
- Quite a few people also enjoy looking through questions about pets they don't have, just to learn more about them.

**What are some things that you like about the site?**

- There's a strong community without a lot of unrelated chatter.
- There's often questions/answers that are interesting to read.
- There's a lot of opportunities and potential to learn new things, and the quality of the format is higher than other Q/A sites.

**What are some things that you don't like about the site?**

- People who ask questions can be too vague sometimes, especially with health questions, and that they don't return most of the time to get their questions answered.
- People who ask questions don't respond to comments, so potentially good questions get closed (possibly leading people to think that those questions are off-topic).
- There are a lot of answers that aren't very good.
- Some of the questions aren't interesting, but that could just be poor wording/format/grammar.
- It should be noted that a couple people didn't have anything to share in this section.

**What are some things that you like about the questions on the site?**

- A lot of questions are clear and well-focused, so they get answers quickly.
- People who ask questions and are engaged in the process push people to write more complete answers.
- They're more useful than other Q/A sites, and more to the point.

**What are some things that you don't like about the questions on the site?**

- Some of the questions aren't very good and aren't interesting.
- The questions tend to be oriented towards the US so any mentions about legal issues might not apply.
- There might need to be a better way to handle the health questions so that they're addressed right away that they need to see a vet. Right now it depends on who is available and willing to write an answer first, which might not be fast enough sometimes.

**What are some things that you like about the answers on the site?**

- Clear and helpful.
- There are some outstanding answers that anticipate problems that weren't asked about originally.
- They all have their own, unique, ideas.

**What are some things that you don't like about the answers on the site?**

- People could be more active in answering questions.
- There are occasional, unsavory, answers that appear, but they usually get deleted pretty quickly.
- Sometimes answers can be kind of rambly.
- There are short and opinionated answers that don't do anything to convince people that they are the right answer.

**What are some things that you like about the other users on the site?**

- People are friendly and passionate about pets, and try to give good advice.
- Users clearly care about building the site and its content.

**What are some things that you don't like about the other users on the site?**

- People don't vote much.
- It would be nice if people stuck around and engaged with the site more.

Comment: How many people responded?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I have 6 responses.